# Memory sharing in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, memory, c++-cli, user-defined-functions

I am using `Windows` OS, `SQL Server`, and `C++/CLI`, I think using `OpenFileMappingFunction()` to communicate memory blocks between `SQL` (maybe an `UDF`) with `C++` is the best approach, so when doing this I avoid writing to table and directly work with memory blocks in C++.

Have you done something similar, can you please tell where to start, or give an example?.

- Is this kind of comunnication possible?

Comment: What a strange mix of tags! Edited.

Comment: could you give more background? why would you want to do this?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GregC: I am trying to use blocks of memory Instead of writing to a file (all this thrwugh `C++`), this is because the tables I am using in `SQL` are composed of numbers (I can see the table as a `matrix`), so I am applying `PCA` or other methods, but I think using a kind of memory map of the numbers in the table could make faster the computing, (I am using tables of `10,000x70` for example), What do you think?, Have you communicate `C++ UDF` with `SQL` using memory sharing or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into PostgreSQL's source code. They've created excellent set of functions for dealing with shared-memory in Windows.